# Telerik for UWP RadDataGrid - Scroll to bottom when item is added

Tags: c#, uwp, telerik

I am trying to have a RadDataGrid (UWP) auto scroll to the bottom when a new item is added.  I have already seen the following:

1. [scroll to last row of RadGrid after binding?](https://www.telerik.com/forums/scroll-to-last-row-of-radgrid-after-binding)
2. [Autoscroll grid to the bottom](https://www.telerik.com/forums/autoscroll-grid-to-the-bottom)

The second one is close, but it doesn't mention the event to bind to for when the ItemsSource is updated.

I am using this in c# with Windows 10 IoT on a Raspberry PI.

Is there an easy way to just automatically get it to scroll?

Comment: Is there a ScrollIntoView method somewhere?  Also maybe try setting SelectedIndex to last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `ObservableCollection` object as the RadDataGrid's ItemsSource. Then, I register [CollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms653375(v=vs.105).aspx) event to detect if the ItemsSource is updated. In the event handler, you could call `DataGrid.ScrollIndexIntoView` method to scroll to the bottom.

Please see my following code sample for reference:

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"/>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        list = new ObservableCollection<Data>{
             new Data { Country = "India", Capital = "New Delhi"},
             new Data { Country = "South Africa", Capital = "Cape Town"},
             new Data { Country = "Nigeria", Capital = "Abuja" },
             new Data { Country = "Singapore", Capital = "Singapore" },
             new Data { Country = "India", Capital = "New Delhi"}
        };
        list.CollectionChanged += List_CollectionChanged;
        DataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    private void List_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            DataGrid.ScrollIndexIntoView(list.Count - 1);
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Data> list { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Capital { get; set; }
}
```